# My sorting is not working in razor view but in my code i am getting the right result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, razor

I have an application in which i have departments view the department table have Id,name,Active and date created columns, I want to sort based on name and date so i wrote the below code in my index controller.

I have tried to pass query parameter and it works fine and my query is generted 100% right but on view it is not showing the right result

```
 public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
        {
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
            var dept = from s in db.Departments
                           select s;
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    dept = dept.OrderByDescending(s => s.Department_Title);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    dept = dept.OrderBy(s => s.Date_Created);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    dept = dept.OrderByDescending(s => s.Date_Created);
                    break;
                default:
                    dept = dept.OrderBy(s => s.Department_Title);
                    break;
            }
            return View(db.Departments.ToList());
        }
```

below is my razor view

```
 <table class="table table-condensed">
        @*<tr>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
            </th>
            <th>
                First Name
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Enrollment Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm })
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>*@



        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Department Name","Index",new {sortOrder=ViewBag.NamesortParm })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Creation Date","Index",new {sortOrder=ViewBag.DateSortParm })
            </th>
            @*<th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date_Modified)
            </th>*@
            <th>Edit/Delete</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department_Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (item.Status != null)
                    {
                        @(item.Status.Value ? Html.Raw("ACTIVE") : Html.Raw("NOT ACTIVE"))
                    }
                    @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)*@
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date_Created)
                </td>
                @*<td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date_Modified)
                </td>*@
                <td colspan="3">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Department_Id }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete?');", @class = "btn btn-sm btn-info" })
                    @*@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Department_Id }) |*@
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Department_Id }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete?');", @class = "btn btn-sm btn-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
```

below is my query which is generated based on department_name click

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Department_Id] AS [Department_Id], 
    [Extent1].[Department_Title] AS [Department_Title], 
    [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Created] AS [Date_Created], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Modified] AS [Date_Modified]
    FROM [dbo].[Departments] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[Department_Title] DESC
```

it should sort the result in the view ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry i was making a normal mistake instead of returning the filtered list i was returning return View(db.Departments.ToList()); BUT IT SHOULD BE return View(dept.ToList());

Answer (score 0):

You have to return your var dept variable since it already contains your sorted list in your switch case the db.department will return you the actual list of department which is inserted in the database. so instead of db.database.toList() use dept.ToList();